# How to open external pages in android using java script?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am Using **cordova 1.8**, and i want to open external webpages using native browser in my app itself, i searched but not got the answer. however i wrote a code snippet.
Any suggestions?

```
<!Doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>demo browser</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="childbrowser.js"></script>
    <script>
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.google.com", { showLocationBar: true });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
hello visitor<br><br>
<button onClick="onDeviceReady();">click to open</button></body>
</html>
```

Comment: try googling "android webview"

Answer (score 0):

Just call intent to view the url:

```
String uri_str;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uri_str);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(i);
```